# Data Multithread Parsing

Tags: python, parsing, python-multithreading, python-asyncio

I'm looking for an opportunity to optimize my Python code for a multithreaded Python application.

My code works in the following way: it downloads sitemap, gathering all links from it into map_links. After that, the Parser function checks on every link found and gathers data on the tag I need.

```
import threading
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {
    'accept':'*/*',
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'
    }

base_url = 'https://example.com/page.php' 
sitemap_url = 'https://example.com/sitemap.xml'    #https://exgfmeetworld.xyz/sitemap.xml

# ф-ция парсинга карты сайта
def sitemap(sitemap_url,headers):                                    
    map_links =[]
    session = requests.Session()
    request =session.get(sitemap_url,headers=headers)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        soup=bs(request.content, 'xml')
        for links in soup.find_all('loc'):
            map_links.append(links.text)

    return map_links

# главная ф-ция парсинга
def parser(base_url,headers):                                          
    session = requests.Session()
    request =session.get(base_url,headers=headers)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        soup=bs(request.content, 'html.parser')
        #keyword = soup.find_all('h1', attrs={'class':'vedaky'})
        keyword = soup.select('h1')[0].get_text()
    else:
        print ('error')
    pass
    return keyword


# главная функция парсинга
def main():
    all_links=sitemap (sitemap_url,headers)
    for i in all_links:
        keyword_pars = parser(i,headers)
        print (keyword_pars)


if _name_ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have tried "multiprocessing import Pool" but it doesn't work for my purpose. I need non-pool decisions because I need much higher performance from the script. I'm planning to use it in more than 20 threads.

Comment: So are you simply trying to scrape multiple links at the same time? instead of simply calling ```parser(i, headers)```,  spawn a new thread?

Comment: I see that you have copied my answer and pasted it as your code in the question, is it OK? Did it work? If so, then accept my answer for future viewers.

Comment: Are you sure the parsing is the slow bit, and not fetching over the network? How did you measure? How long does it take now? How fast does it need to be?

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it without the proper links but I think this will do what you want it to. It works by passing a list to the parser function, which is of course passed by reference, then the output is 'saved' to an index of the list.

Note that I haven't added any much needed error handling.

```
import threading
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

SITE_MAP_URL = 'https://exgfmeetworld.xyz/sitemap.xml'
BASE_URL = 'https://example.com/page.php'

HEADERS = {
    'accept':'*/*',
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'
    }

def get_site_map() -> list:
    request = requests.get(SITE_MAP_URL, headers=HEADERS, timeout=5)

    links = []

    if request.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs(request.content, "html.parser")

        links = [l.text for l in soup.find_all("loc")]

    return links


def parser(link: str):
    request = requests.get(link, headers=HEADERS, timeout=5)

    if request.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs(request.content, "html.parser")

        return soup.find("h1").text

    return None


# - MAIN
links = get_site_map()

parser_output = []

pool = ThreadPool(20)

results = pool.map(parser, links)

pool.close()
pool.join()

print(results)
```

Comment: @SwenRhodian That's an error related to your scrapping, not the threading which i have added.

Comment: Joshua Nixon thank you for reply, the link you asked is https://exgfmeetworld.xyz/sitemap.xml. I think I have passed into question the wrong code, cause I was trying to launch your variant on my machine. Regarding the code itself I have several qustions: 1) your script is parsing only BASE_URL and not taking the links found on sitemap.xml. 2) from your code I see that each URL initiates a separate thread, how to limit threads and launch my script with thread count - 20.

Comment: It only uses BASE_URL because thats what your initial code did. Ill update my answer in a second

Comment: Should be what you want, since there is so many links it will still take sometime at only 20 threads.

Comment: I have already tried through multiprocessing (as I wrote initially in my question). For me to launch a separate process for each thread is not a good option.

Comment: The  dummy ThreadPool is a wrapper around the threading module. If i didn't use it, i would be writing my own which did the exact same thing.

Comment: Pool is not working for me. I need another solution.